# Capturing current weight on Turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using Turtelbot for my work, and in my setup, Turtlebot is loaded and unloaded with stuff (it is programmed to deliver items), and I do not want the robot to be overloaded beyond its capacity, or even reach 75% of that capacity.

Does the robot publish the current weight currently placed on it? or the weight put on its top? ... if not, is there an alternative? is there some data we can capture and manipulated that would indicate, directly or indirectly, the current weight or the capacity level?

For example, does the weight place on the robot affect its active speed? can can we capture the robot current speed and use it as an indicator  for the current weight placed on the robot? ... is there some other data published by the robot, or its /odom specially that can help in this regard?

Thank for your time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244888/capturing-current-weight-on-turtlebot/) by [samiSH](https://answers.ros.org/users/24287/samish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no specific sensor on the Turtlebot that allows querying it's weight. In principle it might be possible to infer robot payload from things like motor current required to move, odometry response etc., but that requires a full set of experiments, reproducible ground conditions etc., so not sure how viable it is.

I think the most reliable way would be using an Arduino to interface a electric scale or load cell and write out the data to ROS via [rosserial_arduino](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials). If you search for "scale arduino" or similar terms, you should find many (pretty cheap) options.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samiSH](https://answers.ros.org/users/24287/samish/) on 2016-10-04**:
Thank you for the prompt feedback and the tip on scale arduino ... i will check it out for sure :))